# NGINX can't connect to GUNICORN socket

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, nginx-config

Ok, I'm going crazy on this one. I have a Flask application which I want to deploy with **gunicorn+nginx**, on debian-12.

When I try to connect to the homepage, I get a **502 Bad Gateway** in the browser and in the **nginx** error log I have:

```
2023/09/07 18:15:36 [crit] 15569#15569: *1 connect() to unix:/home/admin/my_app/app.sock failed
(13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XX.XXX, server: xxxx,
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/admin/my_app/app.sock:/", host:
"xxxxxx.yyy.zzz"
```

This is what I have on my configurations:
**NGINX**

On my **sites-available** (and linked this to **sites-enabled**) folder:
server {
listen 80;

```
server_name xxxx xxxxx.yyy.zzz/;

location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/admin/my_app/app.sock;
    }
}
```

Note: nginx runs as **www-data** user

**Gunicorn**
I have a service created on systemd as (myapp.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=my app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=admin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/my_app
Environment="PATH=/home/admin/my_app/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=unix:app.sock -m 777 main:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.
```

This is working ok, this is the result of systemctl status:

```
myapp.service - xxxx server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-09-07 18:04:07 EDT; 31min ago
   Main PID: 15471 (gunicorn)
     CGroup: /system.slice/osgr-sales.service
             ├─15471 /home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/python3 /home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=unix:app.sock -m 777 main:app
             ├─15472 /home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/python3 /home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=unix:app.sock -m 777 main:app
             └─15473 /home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/python3 /home/admin/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=unix:app.sock -m 777 main:app

Sep 07 18:04:07 xxxxx systemd[1]: Started myapp.service - xxxxx server.
Sep 07 18:04:07 xxxxx gunicorn[15471]: [2023-09-07 18:04:07 -0400] [15471] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Sep 07 18:04:07 xxxxx gunicorn[15471]: [2023-09-07 18:04:07 -0400] [15471] [INFO] Listening at: unix:app.sock (15471)
Sep 07 18:04:07 xxxxx gunicorn[15471]: [2023-09-07 18:04:07 -0400] [15471] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Sep 07 18:04:07 xxxxx gunicorn[15472]: [2023-09-07 18:04:07 -0400] [15472] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15472
Sep 07 18:04:07 xxxxx gunicorn[15473]: [2023-09-07 18:04:07 -0400] [15473] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15473
```

Everything seems ok, but whenever I try to reach my app, I get the "Bad Gateway error" described above.

Seems it must be some authorization problem but I have no idea what might be, since I setup 777 permissions on the socket, should work, right?

This is what I have tried so far:

1- Change the socket (app.sock) group to **www-data**
2- Add **www-data** user to **admin** group
3- Manually change the socket owner to **www-data**
4- Change the folder **/home/admin/my_app** group to **www-data**

None of these work, I keep getting the "Bad gateway"/(13: Permission denied) error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago and it was because www-data didn't have read permissions for /home/admin.

You should check that. www-data should have permissions to navigate to your folder and read the .sock file.

Comment: Yeah it was an authorization problem, I changed:

Group=www-data to admin and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by FeanDoe, it was a permissions problem.

I changed the group from www-data to admin on my service file:

Group=admin

And it's working fine now.